# Проект, компилирующийся в VS 2017 выдаёт ошибку линковки в VS 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, sfml, линковка

Создал в VS 2017 консольное приложение, через NuGet скачал sfml_graphics и написал такой нехитрый код

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main() {
    sf::RenderWindow win({ 100,100 }, "Danmauk");
    sf::CircleShape c(50);
    while (true) {
        sf::Event ev;
        win.pollEvent(ev);
        win.clear();
        win.draw(c);
        win.display();
    }
}
```

и всё работает нормально.

Однако при создании аналогичного проекта в VS 2019 вылазит ошибка о неразрешённых внешних символах по типу этой `Ошибка LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "__declspec(dllimport) public: bool __thiscall sf::Window::pollEvent(class sf::Event &)" (__imp_?pollEvent@Window@sf@@QAE_NAAVEvent@2@@Z) в функции _main`.

В чём проблема и как её исправить?

Comment: `sfml_windows`, `sfml_system` установите

Comment: они установились вместе с `sfml_graphics`

Comment: @kust Вам же вроде как пишется "ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ" библиотеку не подключили судя по всему(ну или не ту версию).

Comment: проблема в том что в 17 ничего подключать не надо было, я же написал действия в обоих случаях аналогичны, но результат разный